# Ошибка ValueError: month out of range

Tags: python

Столкнулся с ошибкой ValueError: month out of range. Подскажите, пожалуйста, причину и как исправить ошибку. Коротко о смысле скрипта: вводим месяц, число, год, получаем на выходе объект данных в определенном формате. Потом буду дописывать скрипт, чтобы выводил только день недели, без введенных данных.

```
%%writefile day_finder.py

import time, datetime
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("month", type = int, help = "Month as a number (1, 12)")
parser.add_argument("day", type = int, help = "Day as a number (1, 31) depending on the month")
parser.add_argument("year", type = int, help = "Year as a 4 digits number (2018)")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--complete", action = 'store_true', help = "Show complete formatted date")
args = parser.parse_args()
d = ()
d = (args.month, args.day, args.year, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0)
date_v = time.strftime("%m,%d,%Y", d)

print (date_v)
```

Запуск скрипта:

```
%%bash

python3 day_finder.py 12 31 2017
```

Comment: `d = (args.year, args.month, args.day, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0)` ?

Comment: когда задаю только три аргумента пишет что мало и надо минимум 9. накидал нолей за все часы, секунды и т.п. и ошибка исчезла. Хотя скорее всего это тоже какое-то кривое решение.

Comment: Используйте: `datetime.date(args.year, args.month, args.day).strftime("%m,%d,%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы определить дату используйте `datetime` (это я так понимаю больше подходит к вашей задаче), для этого необходимо 3 входных параметра в формате `int` - год, месяц и число, порядок строгий:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(args.year, args.month, args.day)
print type(datetime.date(2018, 9, 16))
# <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Вы попробовали сформировать кортеж и использовать модуль `time`. У вас получился кортеж вот такой структуры:

```
d = (9, 16, 2018, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

При выполнении `date_v = time.strftime("%m,%d,%Y", (9, 16, 2018, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))` получаете ошибку, что 16-го месяца не бывает. В некоторых случаях команда отработала бы (12 - станет например 2012), но результат был бы неверный:

```
time.strftime("%m,%d,%Y", (12, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
# '09,09,2012'
```

Правиться строгим указанием год, месяц, день и далее. Т.е. в форматировании вы можете как угодно указать, а вот кортеж подстраивать не нужно - там строго.